# How to create a work item in python using either TFSAPI or requests, ..etc

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-devops, tfs

AM currently writing a rest api python script to interact with azure devops and I wanted to create a work item but am getting 401 or 404 errors. I followed the url query to do a post but I seem not to find the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this official  [Azure DevOps Python API](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) doc.

> It contains Python APIs for interacting with and managing Azure
> DevOps. These APIs power the Azure DevOps Extension for Azure CLI. To
> learn more about the Azure DevOps Extension for Azure CLI, visit the 
> [Microsoft/azure-devops-cli-extension repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension).

Here is some [example code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/blob/768aff8971aad2e194fa26d796d47b3a67292b4e/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/boards/work_item.py#L24) for creating work item in python.

Besides, it is supported to use `requests` to call [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). In this way, you need to create a [personal access token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) first. (Make sure you select the correct scope, in your scenario at least have the create work item permission).

Then you can use the PAT to create the basic auth header, and make the request:

```
import requests
import base64

pat = 'tcd******************************tnq'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json-patch+json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}

url = "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.0"

payload = "[\n  {\n    \"op\": \"add\",\n    \"path\": \"\/fields\/System.Title\",\n    \"from\": null,\n    \"value\": \"Sample task\"\n  }\n]"

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```